# Ubuntu boot showing Resume: libgcrypt Version: 1.5.0

Tags: 12.10, boot, startup, libgcrypt

My boot is very slow, when it is loading displays `Resume: libgcrypt Version: 1.5.0`

After ~20 seconds it continues booting and lets me log in.

[Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyMXiV_Oztg) that I made showing what I mean.

Computer Model: `Samsung Series 5 NP550P5C-T01US 15"`
Running: Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: You really think that 15 seconds is *slow*? Is 50% fast that what I wait, and I have a QuadCore..

Comment: In comparison to my windows yes. Windows boots in 16 seconds for me where Ubuntu takes 26 seconds. I I mostly want to know how I can fix the "Resume: libgcrypt Version: 1.5.0" from showing at all if anything or what it is. I know it's not slow compared to other systems but something seems to be wrong still.

Answer (score 2):

What I can tell you is: **Your system has no problem**

Your video is showing that you **can** boot into Ubuntu and the speed is *normal* (a subjective topic). The boot speed depends for each hardware. My PC, a QuadCore, boot in ~30 seconds. I'm telling you this to have a reference :)

The message displayed is not a problem. Not all the Ubuntu users see the same images while booting, that is variant.

`libgcrypt` is a package that is installed by default in almost all the GNU/Linux system. To discover more information about it see [the Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libgcrypt) or [the GNU entry](http://www.gnu.org/software/libgcrypt/).

Comment: Fair enough. Is there anyway to hide it so it just shows the Ubuntu logo then like it is supposed to while booting?

Comment: @jesse3mail Well, that is something that you can do (I think). I'll research it and see if other users know how to hide/change it..

Answer (score 0):

You quite possibly have a wrong/outdated resume-device-entry somewhere (`/etc/uswsusp.conf`, `/etc/default/grub`, `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`).

You can list all available block devices with their UUIDs and labels with help of the `blkid` command.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo apt-get remove --purge uswsusp

This will solve the problem.